# How i show login user data in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem with get the data of loged user

```
 int id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
      string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
           var Query = from st in db.UserProfiles
                   where st.UserId == id
                   select st;
           return View(Query);
```

Comment: I want to show logged user details in view but it is not working

Comment: Whats not working. Are you getting an exception? Is the value of `Query` null?

Comment: It showing "Children could not be evaluated"

Comment: Where is it showing that? You need to be more specific about what is happening and what if any errors are thrown. Is the value of `Query` valid? Why are you returning `IQueryable` to the view?

Comment: So please tell me what i need to do , i only want to show the logged user details

Comment: What details do you want to display? You haven't responded to any of the queries in my last comment.

Comment: i want to show the Firstname ,Lastanme etc

Comment: I give up - you wont answer the questions or explain the problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  i want to show the userprofile table data when user in logged in mvc 4, Sorry for that if i am not able to explain, i think now you understand

Answer (score 0):

simply use `User` property of Controller for that.

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```

and if you need to use any of User's attribute in your view, or User itself, populate it to a model, and use accordingly.

Comment: What properties of User you want to use?

Comment: eg, let's say, you need Email address of logged in user. you can use:
`string email = db.UserProfiles
           .Where(a => a.UserName.Contains(User.Identity.Name))
           .First().Email;`

Comment: I do not able to get the data in Query variable

Comment: I gave get email id and there user id but data is not showing

Comment: yes, as i told you, you should map it to some model (eg, UserProfileViewModel), pass it to your view, and use it accordingly there.